# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'). What to do?

Tags: javascript, console, web-deployment-project

I'm designing a quiz app, but while console logging for a click event, this statement showed up on the console.
Code -

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", function startGame() {
  console.log("started");
});
```

what should i do to show the statement on my console???

Comment: So, the `startButton` variable doesn't point to an existing DOM element.

Comment: you can try to use `alert("started");` instead of `console.log("started");` to check whether or not the function is invoked.

Comment: I have declared the startButton as -
const startButton = document.getElementById("start-btn");

Comment: even on using alert inplace of console.log, No alert is being generated... instead the console shows - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this error it means that your start button is null. 2 possibilities:

1. Your selector for startButton is incorrect. So you have to adjust your selector.
2. Your selector is correct but your button is not in the DOM yet. So you have a problem with timing. Try to add the eventlistener at the end of your code